# why my Word Break program has a Segment fault

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
    vector<bool> dp(s.size() + 1, false);
    dp[0] = true;
    for(int i = 1; i != s.size() + 1; i++){
        for(auto& word : wordDict){
            //i - word.size() >= 0 will be Segmentation fault
            //but i >= word.size() not
            if(i >= word.size() && 
            dp[i - word.size()] && s.substr(i - word.size(), word.size()) == word){
                dp[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[s.size()];
}

int main(){
    string s = "leetcode";
    vector<string> wordDict = {"leet", "code"};
    if(wordBreak(s, wordDict)) cout << "true" << endl;
    else cout << "false" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some code to solve leetcode 139.
In workBreak, when I use `i - word.size() >= 0` will segment fault, but `i >= word.size` not, why?
please tell me the details.
It may be about string.substr().
I think the i - word.size() >= 0 is equal to i >= word.size.

Comment: Segmentation faults result from undefined behaviour and will not necessarily happen at an understandable or predictable point in the program. Enable more compiler warnings and use tools like valgrind.

Comment: This is evidently not your actual, compiled code, given the missing semicolon after `string s = "leetcode"`.

Comment: It seems as if you intend to allocate one extra element in `dp` so that you can use 1-based indexing. Please do not do that. 0-based indexing is your friend. You will write fewer bugs in the long run that way. Even much higher-level languages like Python and Javascript also use 0-based indexing.

Comment: sorry.my actual code was cin.To be convenient, i write this.I have fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

`i - word.size()` is unsigned integer, because `word.size()` is unsigned. Therefore `i - word.size() >= 0` is always true.

See conversion rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Section "Usual arithmetic conversions":

> If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

`int` and `unsigned int` have the same conversion rank, because they have the same number of bytes. This is explained in the section "Integer promotions".

Comment: "Else, both operands undergo implicit conversion to the unsigned type counterpart of the signed operand's type." **Why on Earth**? Who thought this was a good idea? In what circumstance would this ever be the clearly preferred behaviour?

Comment: To be more constructive: this answer would be better if it talked through the logic on that page to arrive at the specific citation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel • it's an evolutionary byproduct in C++, from C, from B.  B itself inspired by BCPL, from CPL specification (since CPL was never implemented).  C++ compatibility with C is both a bane and a boon.  This is one of the banes.

Comment: Okay (and I realize all of that), but that only kicks the question back to the people responsible for *those* standards.